# JQuery adding support for different value names

Tags: jquery, css

I would like the below script to accept the value color in another language. How do I change the script to accept the field-value of '5f01264e722ae' and change it to the associated predetermined css value? i.e. input value is midnightblue and change it to css value blue.

Thank you for your help.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    var fieldId = "5f0124e773aa8"; 
    var defaultText = "my name"; 
    
    if(!jQuery('input[data-field-id="'+fieldId+'"]').length)
        return;
        
    var $el = jQuery('<div class="sw_poster_text2">').html(defaultText);
    $el.appendTo(jQuery('.woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images'));
    
    jQuery(document).on('change keyup','input[data-field-id="'+fieldId+'"]',function(){
        var v = jQuery(this).val() || defaultText;
        jQuery('.sw_poster_text2').html(v);
        
    }).trigger('change');
    $("select[data-field-id='5f01264e722ae']").change(function() {
        var color = $(this).find('option:selected').data('wapf-label')
        $(".sw_poster_text2").css("color", color);
    });  
});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @epostema. Hope you like it here. What exactly is your goal? What's working so far? What's not working or what do you need help with?

Comment: @PeterKA Thank you. Some of the input fields do not match the exact css property values so I need to be able to define which is which. While we are at it, I have multiple input fields which have to do different changes to the CSS (color change, transform rotate, font types) basically I want a print on a product based on the customers choices from a select list and radio buttons (different fieldId's). Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color like this

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    var fieldId = "5f0124e773aa8"; 
    var defaultText = "my name"; 
    
    if(!jQuery('input[data-field-id="'+fieldId+'"]').length)
        return;
        
    var $el = jQuery('<div class="sw_poster_text2">').html(defaultText);
    $el.appendTo(jQuery('.woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images'));
    
    jQuery(document).on('change keyup','input[data-field-id="'+fieldId+'"]',function(){
        var v = jQuery(this).val() || defaultText;
        jQuery('.sw_poster_text2').html(v);
        
    }).trigger('change');
    $("select[data-field-id='5f01264e722ae']").change(function() {
        var color = $(this).find('option:selected').data('wapf-label');
        if(color == 'midnightblue')
            color = 'blue';
        $(".sw_poster_text2").css("color", color);
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input data-field-id="5f0124e773aa8" />
<select data-field-id="5f01264e722ae">
<option data-wapf-label="black">Black</option>
<option data-wapf-label="red">Red</option>
<option data-wapf-label="yellow">Yellow</option>
<option data-wapf-label="midnightblue">Midnight Blue</option>
</select>
<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images"></div>
</form>
```